# Monday and Sunday of previous week in Unix timestamp AND in New Zealand timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I was wondering what would be the best way to tackle getting the unix timestamps of Monday and Sunday in New Zealand timezone while the system clock (AWS Lambda) is in a different timezone.

I've tried the below and it seems to work well in my local computer however obviously when executed on AWS, it'll be a different timezone.

Can someone please suggest the best way to deal with timezones so the code can run on whatever location?

```
var monday = moment().day(-13).startOf('day').toDate().getTime() // Monday last week
 var sunday = moment().day(-7).startOf('day').toDate().getTime() // Sunday last week
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix Timestamp always give time in UTC regardless of your position. To get the local time of your position please apply the timezone offset to the unix timestamp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You can use [Moment-Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to work with [IANA time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in Moment.
- New Zealand has two different IANA time zone identifiers:

  - `Pacific/Auckland` covers most of New Zealand, which uses UTC+12:00 during standard time, and UTC+13:00 during daylight saving time.
  - `Pacific/Chatham` covers the Chatham Islands which is also part of New Zealand.  However, Chatham uses UTC+12:45 during standard time, and UTC+13:45 during daylight saving time.
- You do not need to convert to a `Date` object.  Moment can give you a Unix timestamp directly, either as seconds with `.unix()`, or as milliseconds with `.valueOf()`.  Both imply a conversion to UTC, as Unix timestamps are inherently UTC based.
- One cannot get a Unix timestamp for an entire day, but rather only for a point in time.  The timestamp you are probably looking for would be at the start of the local day, which is always midnight (`00:00`) in New Zealand (but not necessarily in *other* time zones on DST transition days, depending on the time of the transition).
- When use Moment's `day` function, `day(-13)` doesn't mean "Monday last week".  It means "*two* Mondays ago."  If you meant "*one* Monday ago", that would be `day(-6)`.  Likewise `day(-7)` means "one Sunday ago.  In both cases, it doesn't count the current day.  For example, since today is Sunday 2019-09-01, `day(-7)` refers to Sunday `2019-08-25`.

Putting this all together:

```
var oneMondayAgoInAuckland = moment.tz('Pacific/Auckland').day(-6).startOf('day').valueOf();
var oneSundayAgoInAuckland = moment.tz('Pacific/Auckland').day(-7).startOf('day').valueOf();
```

At the moment, these return `1566734400000` and `1566648000000` respectively.